# Kendo Multidropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am initializing two kendo multiselect dropdowns when loading my page. First one will conatin data from the modal which is rendering properly. When select some items 2 or 3 from dropdown and on close event a json call will be made to populate the second multiselect dropdown. I am getting the json data but the second dropdown is not binding with the data.

Initialize both the dropdowns:

```
 function PopulateClientNamesDropDown() {


          $("#clientNamesDropDown").kendoMultiSelect({
                                autoBind: false,
                                autoClose: false,
                                dataTextField: "text",
                                dataValueField: "value",
                                placeholder: "Select Client...",
                                itemTemplate: $("#ScriptTemplate").html(),
                                dataSource: clientDropDownData,
                                close: function(e) {
                                    GetSiteNames();
                                }
                            });
        }


        function PopulateSiteNamesDropDown() {


             $("#siteNamesDropDown").kendoMultiSelect({
                autoBind: false,
                autoClose: false,
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                placeholder: "Select Site...",
                itemTemplate: $("#ScriptTemplate").html(),
                dataSource: clientDropDownData

            });
        }
```

Close event of first dropdown:

```
function GetSiteNames()
{
    var jqXhr = $.getJSON('/Report/GetSitesofSelectedClient', { selectedClientCode: "Aggregates" }, 'json');

       jqXhr.done(function (data)
       {
             alert(data);
             $("#siteNamesDropDown").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(data);
       });  
   }

}
```

1. In alert function i am able to see the returned json data but not rendering
2. The data from the first multiselect dropdown is not getting on close event. So   currently I am hardcoded the value.

Answer (score 1):

use kendo data source to create multi select elements list.

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: {
    data: ["One", "Two"]
  }
});
```

.Value method is for selecting list of elements or it will give you list of selected elements if you don't pass any arguments to it.

Answer (score -1):

The following code shows how to use cascading kendo multiselect using jquery:

```
var productsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
type: "odata",
serverFiltering: true,
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "Data URl pass here for product datasource",
    }
}
});

$("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
 autoBind: false,
 dataTextField: "ProductName",
 dataValueField: "ProductID",
 dataSource: productsDataSource
});

$("#suppliers").kendoMultiSelect({
 autoBind: false,
 dataTextField: "CompanyName",
 dataValueField: "SupplierID",
 dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "Data URl pass here for Suppliers datasource" 
        }
    }
},
change: function() {
    var filters = buildFilters(this.dataItems());
    productsDataSource .filter(filters);
}
});

function buildFilters(dataItems) {
   var filters = [],
   length = dataItems.length,
   idx = 0, dataItem;

for (int idx=0; idx < length; idx++) {
    dataItem = dataItems[idx];

    filters.push({
        field: "SupplierID",
        operator: "eq",
        value: parseInt(dataItem.SupplierID)
    });
 }
 return filters;
 }
```